# PhpMyAdmin Missing parameter:

Tags: database

Everything was working fine until this moment I want to create a new database and I'm receiving this error

```
db_create.php: Missing parameter: new_db (FAQ 2.8)
```

Also when I was trying to export my database I also receive the following error

```
export.php: Missing parameter: what (FAQ 2.8)
export.php: Missing parameter: export_type (FAQ 2.8)
```

When I looked it FAQ 2.8 from the suggested link in PHPMYADMIN

> 2.8 I get "Missing parameters" errors, what can I do?
>
> Here are a few points to check:
>
> - In config.inc.php, try to leave the $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] directive    empty. See also FAQ 4.7.
> - Maybe you have a broken PHP installation or you need to upgrade your    Zend Optimizer. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31134.
> - If you are using Hardened PHP with the ini directive    varfilter.max_request_variables set to the default (200) or another
>     low value, you could get this error if your table has a high number
>     of columns. Adjust this setting accordingly. (Thanks to Klaus
>     Dorninger for the hint).
> - In the php.ini directive arg_separator.input, a value of ";" will    cause this error. Replace it with "&;".
> - If you are using Hardened-PHP, you might want to increase request    limits.
> - The directory specified in the php.ini directive session.save_path    does not exist or is read-only.

I did tried with php.ini to make sure that I've `session.save_path = "/tmp"`

I'm using Mac Xserver and running with `MAMP` I did tried everything to restart my server and nothing help.

Please if anyone help me to give me some suggestion.

Apologize if I post in a wrong place.

Comment: So what about the other five recommendations in that FAQ item?

Comment: Hi @womble, I couldn't find the config.inc file in my Mac, and number 2 I don't think that is related server and for the rest I can't figure it out how :/

Comment: http://server-support.co/blog/sysadmin/phpmyadmin-import-php-missing-parameter-problem-solved/

Answer (score 1):

Please check available space and permissions on your mysql datadir location.

To further isolate the cause, try to create the database from the mysql command line.  If this fails, it's mysql problem, not phpMyAdmin's.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if you have permissions at directory configured at session.save_path on php.ini.
Probably you changed the Apache user/group and there's no permission for this directory.

To solve:
1) chmod 777 at directory (this is unsecure)
OR
2) change the directory owner to match with Apache needs.